# Airfoil- concave top and bottom

Tags: aircraft-design

I remember building a radio controlled model in the early 90s with concave wing  ribs/surfaces top and bottom...both sides of the wing were undercambered...

It was a very great flying model...60" wingspan...and it flew as well as any other airfoil design...it was a testy build, covering the wing surfaces with monokote..other than that it was a fun craft...never understood how it flew so well by violating all the 'rules?'

Comment: Hi and welcome to [aviation.se]! This place is a bit different than most online fora - We're all about questions and answers, not general discussion. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to find out what makes a good question - that'll help you get a good feel for the place. That said, I'm not really sure you have an actual question, so this will probably end up getting closed. If you do have a question, feel free to [edit] your post to ask it more explicitly. You can do that even if your post is closed, then it will likely get reopened.

Comment: Undercambered bottom follows the "rules", undercambered top has been tried in small scale Kline-Fogleman wing designs. What you are describing resembles a KFm-5b.  A picture or drawing would help.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the "rules" people are traditionally taught about creation of lift, basically that a wing is a semi-venturi that is sucked up by venturi effect as it moves, is a gross oversimplification that overlooks most of what is going on, which is the wing motivating a large package of air to move down and creating a Newtonian action/reaction, of which the venturi effect is a part.

Anything that is more or less flat-ish, moved through the air at some angle, will make some amount of lift if it's able to induce some of the air to move from up here to down there as it passes.  The front door of your house, your hand stuck out the window of a car, or a wing with a weird reverse curve on top.  Enough to make an RC airplane fly at least.  Probably wouldn't work so well with a full size one.